# Passing arguments with changing values to Task -- Behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, scope, task-parallel-library

Scenario: An asynchronous task in a loop executes a method containing arguments that change as the program continues:

```
while(this._variable < 100)
{
    this._variable++; 
    var aTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        aList.add(this._variable);
        update(this._savePoint);
    });
}
```

If the loop runs faster than the tasks complete, will the list add the current value of the variable or is the variable saved locally and the original value added?

Comment: Check this out by Jon Skeet: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Closures close over variables, not values. Therefore, incrementing `_variable` *can* alter the behavior of the task that refers to it.

You can prevent this by making a local copy:

```
while (this._variable < 100)
{
    this._variable++;
    int local = _variable;
    var aTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        aList.add(local);
        update(this._savePoint);
    });
}
```

Or you could pass the value to the task as state:

```
while (this._variable < 100)
{
    this._variable++;
    var aTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(object state =>
    {
        aList.add((int)state);
        update(this._savePoint);
    }, this._variable);
}
```

These both work by copying the value of `_variable` to a new temporary variable. In the first case the `local` variable is defined inside the scope of the loop, so you get a new one for every iteration. In the second case, you make a copy of the value of `_variable` when you pass it to the Task as the `state` argument. If `_variable` were a reference type, these solutions wouldn't work; you'd have to perform a clone.

Comment: What if the variable is an instance of a class? `SomeClass localVariable = this._variable` within the loop.  Being a reference, how would you make sure you don't receive a changed state.

Comment: @Moyler: you would have to clone the instance inside the loop, which means you create a new instance and make the values of its properties identical to those of the original instance.

Comment: Thank you, I needed that confirmed. Also, I originally meant for my example to have a reference type.  Great to get a two for one deal though.