# TcpListener handle of multiple clients

Tags: tcplistener

I created MyListener which will start listening (using TcpListener) on his own thread upon creation. the TcpListener should handle multiple clients so i am running inside infinte while and handle each client in special task.

this is my code:

```
public class MyListener
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageReceived;

    public MyListener()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(Listen);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;

        try
        {
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8977);
            server.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var msg = GetMessageFromClient(client);
                        MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs { Message = msg });
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {


                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        client.Close();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (server != null)
                server.Stop();
        }

    }

    private string GetMessageFromClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        var i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
        return message;
    }
}
```

here are my questions:

1. how can i ensure that the task handle the client will use the client i pass to it when i start the task and not different client (becuase after the task start we return to the AcceptTcpClient method and may get new client)
2. in my example and with multiple clients handled by the same method ("GetMessageFromClient") do i need to put some kind of locking on this
   method?

Comment: first question answered by this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179691/passing-arguments-with-changing-values-to-task-behaviour

Comment: for the second question: every thread get his own stack and local variable are on that stack so every thread is isolated regarding this method